# C# - Windows Forms Application Monitor

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows

This is not really a problem per say but I have this requirement at work whereby I need to write a windows application in C# that will monitor all our internal and external systems. Some of these systems are websites and some are windows applications which are constantly polling data the whole time to and from the database including soap api calls. What my application needs to do is monitor these systems and notify relevant users whenever downtime occurs and for how long has it been offline.

I have done the database design using SQL Server as a DBMS but I'm stuck in terms of implementation. What approach can I use to achieve this? TCP/IP?
This application should run every x seconds.

I have created a few flags inside an enum that will constantly check the application state if its ok, in erroneous state or whether it should warn the user. In addition to this I have also created a constructor that will initialize all the components of the service monitor through a DLL.

Something like so:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum ClientApplicationState
    {
        ERROR = 0,
        WARNING = 1,
        OK = 2
    }

/// <summary>
/// Constructor which sets up and initalizes all the components for the Service Monitoring DLL
/// </summary>
/// <param name="applicationName">The Name Of The Application</param>
/// <param name="port">The port on which to listen to</param>
/// <param name="timerPeriod"> Optional time in milisecinds to overide the default update freq (default is 1000)</param>
public ServiceMonitor(string applicationName, short port, int timerPeriod = 1000)
{
    _messages = new List<string>();
    _state = ClientApplicationState.OK;
    //TODO: Throw port exception
    try
    {
        _monClient = new MonitoringClient(applicationName, ClientApplicationState.OK, "Starting Up",
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, port);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    InitTimer(timerPeriod);
    _updateTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

The websites are hosted and are live and the windows applications are running on our Windows 2012 R2 server.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are far too general to answer. But I think you need to really look at the "things" you intend to monitor. And then you need to understand services (if that is the approach you want to take - which seems appropriate).

A service is started and runs continuously (logically). Your idea of running "every x seconds" is a bit misleading. You may want your service to "check" every x seconds, but don't confuse that idea with the application executing. And, of course, you should be able to configure that frequency - another feature you should plan for.

To be honest, I don't really see the purpose of a database yet. And based on what I read, I suggest you stop thinking about the implementation and start thinking about this service as a whole. Where you store data is irrelevant at this point in time. You need to decide what the service does (and "monitor for downtime" is a very premature requirement), for what "things" it does this service, and how it will respond. What happens when your service stops? Do you monitor the monitor? Who will install/configure it? Will it provide any information while running? And so on.

And before you go further, it seems like you need to write what is a rather complex service/system. Something MS (and others) have already done - like the MS Operations Manager https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh230741.aspx. If you're going to reinvent the wheel (at least partially), then it may help you to look at the documentation to see what it does, how it is configured, the concepts behind it, etc.

Comment: I think the word "service" has been slightly misinterpreted out of context. The applications I need to monitor are not Windows Services nor  am I supposed to write a Windows Service - just to clear that up.